# Hibernate Lazy Load Behaves as Eager

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a `EntityA` which has couple of `OneToOne` joins & `ManyToOne` join with `EntityB`. `EntityB` has couple of `OneToOne` joins.

```
public class EntityA {

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityD", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   protected EntityD entityD;

   @JoinColumn(name = "entityB")
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   protected EntityB entityB;
   ...
   ...
   ...
}

public class EntityB {

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityc", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   protected EntityC entityc;
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

When I do `EntityARepository.findById()` multiple sql calls(approx 40 calls) made for all the joins even though the FetchType is mentioned as LAZY. Since it is impacting performance and to reduce this unwanted calls I have removed the fetch type from the `OneToOne` joins of `EntityA` which reduced the calls of `OneToOne` joins.

After I removed the fetch types for `OneToOne` joins from `EntityB`, I'm receiving `ORA-00913: too many values` error.

What is the best way to make this sql calls as lazy for this type of joins.

I tried using `JOIN FETCH` in the query but it didn't work as expected. It still made the join calls as Eager.

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM EntityA a " +
          "LEFT JOIN FETCH a.entityB b " +
          "LEFT JOIN FETCH b.entityC c" +
          "WHERE a.id = ?1")
EntityA findById(Long id);
```

I tried updating `EntityA` & `EntityB` join from `ManytoOne` -> `OneToOne` but still same error `ORA-00913: too many values`.

Comment: `JOIN FETCH` will make them eager, that is the whole point of adding that to a query. LAZY on an `@OneToOne` will only work (AFAIK) with bytecode enhancements so you need to add additional configuration and properties.

Comment: Agreed. LAZY fetch type should handle the LAZY Loading. But it didn't work, am I missing something?